# Pinescript how to place labels on the left side of the subwindow

Tags: pine-script

I have an indicator which produces 4 rows of interrupted lines in a sub-window.
I use the plot function for each line like this:

```
plot(12, color=color.black, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
```

I would like to label these lines in the window. Is there a way to use the window together with this plot function the the label ends up on the left side of the line?

Thank you in advance
Adam

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Too bad, thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is attach your entire script to the left scale.

```
indicator("Test", scale=scale.left)
```